# Разрядность проекта в Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, x86-64

Открыл чужой проект проект в Visual Studio 2015 и увидел что его можно собрать только под 64-ную платформу. Стало интересно почему, перерыл все настройки, ничего не нашел. Объясните, пожалуйста, чайнику как так?

Comment: Нужно больше информации.

Comment: Какого рода информации нужно больше? К примеру, вот этот проект: https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan

Comment: Вам интересно, почему можно собрать только под 64бита? Или вам нужно разобраться, как его собрать под 32-бита?

Comment: Первое. Интересно почему его можно собрать только под 64 бита. Если создать новый проект, то есть выбор под 32 или под 64. А если открыть этот - можно только под 64 бита. Очень интересно почему. Нагуглить не получилось, по всем настройкам проекта и решения внимательно прошелся еще раз - ничего не нашел. Мистика какая-то.

Comment: Update: 32 бита удалось добавить через диспетчер конфигураций. Наверное вопрос закрыт, странно только что с самого начала 32 бит не было.

Comment: @AugustPro не добавили соответствующую конфигурацию. Или удалили...